# Instagram API call returns data for /users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN but returns empty data set for other api calls

Tags: instagram-api

Example /self/access_toke returns complete information about the user.The information includes the user likes, follows too.. But when i call /users/self/likes it returns empty data.The likes count from /self has to be returned for /self/likes too..but API call returns empty set.

Comment: Might be helpful if you could add more code for us to trace.

Comment: Is your app in sandbox mode?